# How to do business with a person which is of different religion?

Tags: sharia, non-muslim, business

The scenario is broad in its macro term, to make it easier, let’s say you have a business partner who is of different religion e.g. Hindu or Christian. You also know that your business partner does business using income source that is not accepted in Islam, e.g.: taking interests on loan. However, if you don't do business with him, things will get complicated for your corporation. Also, in a huge economy, when there are so many corporation who rely heavily on interest income, how to deal with that, financially.

Answer (score 3):

Through all Hadiths and Ayas, Muslims have no problem doing business with non Muslims. But in case of partnership, many scholars said it is not a proper work, because the non Muslims do not pay attention to Halal and Haram.

1. The reference for this is a Hadith from Muhammad (pbuh) shows it is not a good work but did not forbid it:

> Ahkam Al-Zemmeh(احکام الذمه), Vol.1, page 183

2. And other reference is a Hadith from Amir Al mo'menin which is located in:

> Wasail Al-shia, Vol.13, Chap.2

Comment: Care to elaborate on it more?

Comment: It depends on! If you want to go for partner ship yes you have to care to elaborate on it. But if you want to just trade or something else there is no need to search and see from where the other side will bring the money. As we have in Islam history that the prophet has been bying from jews and christians but not from Mushrik

Comment: In Islamic countries many people and or institution depend on money earned from interest; I don't know what you are going to denote these people as.

Comment: you have to mention that any interests are not haram. Just those ones that are near to Reba. Please le me a day to bring you fatwa about this

Comment: Haha, the corner cases... let me know if you find anything insightful.

Comment: Your first comment would be better off as part of the answer.

Comment: Could you provide the hadees which you have provided reference for in 1 and 2. And please user `ctrl-o` put down an ordered list and `ctrl-u` for an unordered one.